# Need To Print Repeated Numbers Just Once / C++

Tags: c++, repeat

Can't use libraries and other methods.

As you can see my program finds the repeated numbers and print it but I need to print the numbers just once.

As example if entered:

`7 1 1 2 1 2 2 9`

It should print

`1 2`

In case there is no any repeated number:

`7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

There should not be any output!

Also note, that the first number is the length of `array`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  unsigned size;
  std::cin >> size;
  int* myArray = new int[size];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      std::cin >> myArray[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < i && !found; j++) {
        found = (myArray[i] == myArray[j]);
    }
    if (!found) {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    } 
  }
   


   delete []myArray;
}
```

Comment: What you get is exactly what you implemented. So, your algorithm does not what you intended to do: print a number if it's not repeated in the trailing array.

Comment: No, 6 is the array length

Comment: Are the inputs guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of two bools as the other user suggested I would use the counter basically doing the same thing but with one variable. The trick is to check if you have already had the number you are checking right now before so that you wouldn't print it again.
And then to check the rest of the list for duplicates.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  unsigned size;
  std::cin >> size;
  int* myArray = new int[size];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      std::cin >> myArray[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    //check if the number has already been found earlier
    for (int j = 0; j < i && !count; j++) {
        if(myArray[i] == myArray[j]) count++;
    }
    //check the rest of the array for the repeated number
    if (!count) {
       for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
        if(myArray[i] == myArray[j]) count++;
       } 
    }
    //print if repeated
    if (count > 1) {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    } 
  }
   
   delete []myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would probably be to use a `set`, but I'm not sure if that's allowed under the "can't use other libraries" rule.

Using just arrays, for each item you could iterate over all the items **before it**, and only print it if it wasn't found there:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < i && !found; j++) {
        found = (myArray[i] == myArray[j]);
    }
    if (!found) {
        cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, need to add a condition to not check the numbers that are just once I think, because if entered 5 1 2 3 4 5, it will print 1 2 3 4 5. Am I right?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, no need to print that numbers, only ones that met more than once.

Comment: `set::insert` do the job : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert
check if the `bool` in the pair is `false`. If it's false, print

Answer (score 2):

The first occurrence of a repeated number has no occurrences before it and at least one after it.
This is reasonably easy to detect:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    bool before = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < i && !before; j++) {
        before = myArray[i] == myArray[j];
    }
    if (!before) {
        bool after = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size && !after; j++) {
            after = myArray[i] == myArray[j];
        }
        if (after)
        {
            cout << myArray[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```